# Ignore disabled state in custom TYPO3 Validator

Tags: validation, typo3, extbase

I have a plugin with a form where User can register, to avoid duplicate registrations I've added a custom Validator which checks if a FE user already contain the email.

```
//This is just the isValid method of the custom validator..
public function isValid($value): void
{
  $existingUser = $this->frontendUserRepository->findByEmail($value)->getFirst();
  if ($existingUser != null) {
    $this->addError(
      'E-mail already registered',
      1592556619
    );
  }
}
```

Because of an additional double opt-in mechanism I would like to disable the new created FE user (which is created in the submit action of the registration form), so far so good.
But now my custom validator didn't find users which are disabled when try to find it by email.

So my question is, how can I tell it that he have to ignore the disabled state of the entry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You will need to configure your repository method to ignore the `disabled` enable field. (See [`enablecolumns` in TCA](https://docs.typo3.org/m/typo3/reference-tca/10.4/en-us/Ctrl/Index.html#enablecolumns).)

You will need to add a custom `findOneByEmail()` method to your repository and configure the query accordingly:

```php
$query = $this->createQuery();
$query->getQuerySettings()
    ->setIgnoreEnableFields(true)
    ->setEnableFieldsToBeIgnored(['disabled']);
```

Afterwards you can execute the query as usual which will now include disabled users:

```php
$query
    ->matching($query->equals('email', $email))
    ->setLimit(1);

return $query->execute()->getFirst();
```

Notice that you should put this in a separate `findOneByEmailIncludingHidden()` or similar to avoid unexpected side-effects and make the special behavior of this query method clear.

(You may have noticed that `findOneBy*` is used here instead of `findBy*` since that will automatically return the first object.)

Comment: I've added it in the initialize method of the action so it also gets applied to the custom validators.

Comment: Why is `setLimit(1)` being ignored when using `$query->execute()`? Or asked differently: WHY do we always need `execute()->getFirst()` to only get exactly one item, also if the limit is set to 1 already? This seems to be odd and is nowhere really documented. With `setLimit(1)->execute()` the result can have multiple items, but only 1 is expected.

Comment: `setLimit()` is not ignored if set, not sure what you mean. And the DB API always is tailored to the broadest case, thus yielding many records. Explicitly fetching only one is only a subset of this. That's why you alyways need to explicitly fetch the first entry, either via method call or breaking a loop after the 1st iteration. You could also skip the limit and do the same but then you risk fetching more records pointlessly.